# In a conductor with a charge in it, will the charge disappear after induced charges come into existence?

Tags: electromagnetism, gauss-law

Consider a charge of $+q$ inside a conducting shell S:

[image]

Now, once we reach equilibrium it must be that [induced charge](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23115/why-does-the-induced-charge-have-to-have-the-same-magnitude-as-the-inducing-char) of equal magnitude and opposite sign(green color) appears on the inner surface of S (and positive induced charge on outer surface)

[image]

Now, consider taking a gaussian surface inside S which contains $+q$, call this surface as F
[image]

Since the electric field must be zero at all points inside a conducting shell, it must be that $\int  \vec{E} \cdot \vec{dS}=0$ because $E=0$ everywhere inside for conducting shell in equilibrium, now for gauss law we have:

$$ \int \vec{E} \cdot dS = \frac{Q_{enclosed}}{\epsilon_o}$$

Setting LHS to zero:

$$ Q=0$$

This means there is no charge inside the surface S, so where did the charge of +q go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is in the statement that

> ... the electric field must be zero at all points inside a conducting shell ...

This is only true for a hollow cavity which we clearly do not have.

Therefore there will just be a standard $\frac{1}{r^2}$ dependence for $\vec E$ inside the shell as if it were just a $+q$ point charge in free space.

Reference: https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_05.html#Ch5-S10

> You should notice carefully one important qualification we have made. We have always said “inside an empty” cavity. If some charges are placed at some fixed locations in the cavity—as on an insulator or on a small conductor insulated from the main one—then there can be fields in the cavity. But then that is not an “empty” cavity.

Comment: Now, that I read this again, if the field inside is non zero, how can the conductor be in equiilbrium?

Comment: What do you mean by in equilibrium? If there were no charge in the middle of the shell, the conductor would remain uncharged.  Adding this positive charge creates a 1/r^2 field (it must do since Gauss never lies!), so then the conductor separates into -ve charge on the inner side and +ve charge on the outer side, as you have drawn it in your diagram.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, in a conductor charges rearrange such that field is zero inside to achieve the least energy state, however what you said suggest non zero field inside @Joe Iddon

Comment: No, the field inside the conductor is still zero since the field created due to the charge separation at the surfaces of the conductor, which is directed inwards, is perfectly balanced by the field due to the positive charge which points outwards.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now, the gauss law only accounts for field caused by charges **inside** the gaussian surface, not the ones outside

Comment: No not quite, it takes into account "the" electric field - I.e. it account for all charges. This is a strange property, but it can be shown that any field that is due to a charge outside the shell will not affect the surface integral of the field over the shell. Only fields due to charges inside affect the surface integral, but this is not because we are not including any external fields, it is just that these contribute zero to the integral.